# How to perform consistent hashing on any Python object that works with hash()?

Tags: python, caching, hashing

I have a Python library that performs a kind of calculation given a parameter-object. A requirement of the parameter object is that it be both hashable and serializable. It's a long calculation, so it memoizes itself. Let's say this is implemented something like this:

```py
# Notes: params *must* be serializable and hashable;
#        equal params *always* produce equal results.
def long_calc(params):
   if params in long_calc._cache:
      return long_calc._cache[params]
   result = _long_calc_but_with_math(params)
   long_calc._cache[params] = result
   return result
long_calc._cache = {}
```

In particular, this calculation is really slow, so I would like to add an optional feature to the function such that, if you provide it with a cache location, it will check for a cache file and either load/return it instead of running the calculation or, if that file is not found, will calculate the result and save it before returning it. This would be something like this:

```py
def long_calc(params, cache=None):
   if params in long_calc._cache:
      return long_calc._cache[params]
   if cache is not None and os.path.isfile(cache):
      return _load_calc_result(cache)
   result = _long_calc_but_with_math(params)
   long_calc._cache[params] = result
   if cache is not None:
      _save_calc_result(cache, result)
   return result
long_calc._cache = {}
```

In typical use, this calculation will be run many times with many sets of parameters, and a given Python instance will likely examine many results. Accordingly, I would like to make this easier for the user and allow them to provide just a cache directory; the `long_calc` function would then be responsible for ensuring that its contents represented a correct/unique hashing of the cached data. My first idea for how to do this was to use the parameter-hashes as directory names; each directory represented a set of parameter values, all of which have the same hash and thus all collide in this schema. The parameters themselves would be serialized out to a file `key-001.pickle` and the result to `val-001.pickle` so that exact parameters could be checked and collisions resolved. I realize this is slow, but the calculations are plenty long enough to justify the wait. For context, this is scientific software, so security is not really a concern, but reproducibility is. I wrote this approach up something like this:

```py
def long_calc(params, cache=None):
   if params in long_calc._cache:
      return long_calc._cache[params]
   if cache is not None:
      cache = _cache_filename(params, cache)
      if os.path.isfile(cache):
         return _load_calc_result(cache)
   result = _long_calc_but_with_math(params)
   long_calc._cache[params] = result
   if cache is not None:
      _save_calc_result(cache, result)
   return result
long_calc._cache = {}

def _cache_filename(params, cache_dir):
   # Get a hash for the params:
   h = hash(params)
   # Turn it into a directory name
   hstr = ('p' if h > 0 else 'n') + str(abs(h))
   hdir = os.path.join(cache_dir, hstr)
   # make it if it doesn't exist
   os.makedirs(hdir, mode=0o755)
   # look for a key that either matches or is not yet filled
   k = 0
   while True:
      # get the keyfile's name
      kfilename = os.path.join(hdir, 'key_%d.pkl' % k)
      if not os.path.isfile(kfilename):
         # Claim this spot
         _save_params(kfilename, params)
         break
      v = _load_params(kfilename)
      if params == v:
         break
      k = k + 1
   # return the value file that matches the key file 
   return os.path.join(hdir, 'val_%d.pkl' % k)
```

For the record I know there's a race condition here and am not worried about it.

This approach worked just fine and tested just fine... until I restarted my python instance. It ends up that [python's hash function is intentionally salted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522626/hash-function-in-python-3-3-returns-different-results-between-sessions) as a security measure, so the line `h = hash(params)` isn't finding a *consistent* hash, which is what I need. This puts me in a bit of a bind because previous versions of the software have already established the norm that the params need to be *hashable* (i.e. via the `hash()` function) to be valid. Changing this requirement to instead be that the params object must be hashable by some other library's schema will break code unless the other library has a drop-in replacement for `hash()`.

**TLDR; Question 1:** Is there a drop-in replacement for `hash(x)` that yields a *consistent* hash of `x` for any (or almost any) `x` normally hashable by `hash(x)`? Note that I'm willing to sacrifice a few unusual edge cases regarding the type of `x` if there's a drop-in for this that is pretty close.

Other answers about this kind of question have pointed at [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html), but it looks to me like with this library where I would need to convert objects like `frozenset`s to a unique string of bytes for hashing, which means it doesn't have a clear replacement for `hash()`. (I can't guarantee that equal parameter objects will have identical serialization strings, only that, once deserialized, the objects will again be equal).

**TLDR; Question 2:** Is there an easy way to make an object that is hashable (via `hash()`) and serializable (into a byte-string that can be different from that of another equal object) work with existing hash-libraries like `hashlib`?

A bit of research shows that you can pass `Python` the environment variable [`PYTHONHASHSEED=0`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) to disable salting. This is basically what I want, but for various reasons I don't think it's a good idea to force/require my users to do this themselves, and, as far as I can tell, you can't update the hash-seed during a python process. This has led me to the uncomfortable conclusion that the best way to get at this problem is possibly to fork/exec and have the child-process manage the calculation/caching of the result with an updated seed. I think that this is a pretty bad solution, and it's hard for me to imagine that there would be a consistent hash algorithm deep in python that just can't be accessed in any other way than this one.

**TLDR; Question 3:** Is there a way to temporarily disable the python hash salting aside from starting a new python process?

One last piece of context is that it's okay if a cache directory for one node/OS/python-version isn't compatible with that of another. But if I have a local cache on my local machine that is being updated within the same context, it should all work correctly. (Also it would be even better if the cache were consistent across all these things! it's just not required of a solution.)

Any other solutions that fall within the constraints I've laid out would also be very welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Change your cache file so that it doesn’t map hash code to result of calculation, but parameters to result of calculation.

Since the calculation takes very long, having to match the parameters shouldn’t be a big deal, even though it is somehow inefficient. And of course you _can_calculate hash codes for parameters that you compared in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix would be to serialize into JSON and then hash that single string whichever way you please. That tends to be pretty stable, but there may be corner cases where it is not giving optimal results, for example when the object has arrays where the order of items may vary. Depends on how cleverly implemented hash() is for your parameter object.

Hashing objects involving walking the properties, running the system implementation of hash() for intrinsic classes, running the custom hash() implementations for other classes, and combining the hash codes. Depending on the properties of the parameters object, you could emulate that. You can find "how to combine hash codes" on stackoverflow.

Again depending on the parameters, you could write the parameter set into a database table. This effectively pushes the hashing down to the database. Obviously this only going to be reasonable only if the parameters have few fields and have no hierarchy.

Speaking of databases, I'd use an in-process database like sqlite and an ORM to store results. It's minimally more or even less work than dealing with files yourself.

Comment: So serializing to a JSON will not work for very simple examples such as a set or frozenset. The order would be critical in these cases. These are simple examples where `hash()` works but this approach would not work.

Comment: I guess I did not explain that very well, A JSON serializer will not be instable itself (it will not reorder anything). But if you had objects { 1, operator_add, 3 } and {3, operator_add, 1} and wanted them to hash to the same value, that would be lost.

Comment: I'm explicitly looking for an example that works for objects like `frozenset`. To quote the original post: "`Other answers about this kind of question have pointed at hashlib, but it looks to me like with this library where I would need to convert objects like frozensets to a unique string of bytes for hashing, which means it doesn't have a clear replacement for hash(). (I can't guarantee that equal parameter objects will have identical serialization strings, only that, once deserialized, the objects will again be equal).`" This same problem exists for the use of a database.

Comment: You missed the main point: On many implementations, hashing a string over different program runs is absolutely not s to stable. Intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is very old, but in python, as far as I know only strings are not session consistent hashes. So you can do something like this. Note that because string hashes are randomised, it means frozen sets cannot be relied upon to give consistent hashes or orders, so we have to find a session independent order for them. The below shows an example that should work for most common data types.

```
    def session_consistent_hash(
        obj : t.Any, hash_object=None
):
    """
    This should be able to take any of the parameters that go into making a metadata object,
    it will essentially function as the hash function for metadata objects which must be
    consistent across python sessions. Python randomises its string hashes.
    """
    if hash_object is None:
        hash_object = hashlib.md5()
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        hash_object.update(obj.encode("utf16"))
    elif isinstance(obj, t.Mapping):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            session_consistent_hash(key, hash_object=hash_object)
            session_consistent_hash(value, hash_object=hash_object)
    elif isinstance(obj, t.Sequence):
        for value in obj:
            session_consistent_hash(value, hash_object=hash_object)
    elif isinstance(obj, t.FrozenSet):
        # the use of hash_object=None will guarantee an order independent
        # of the session, and we can then use that order to update the final hash.
        session_consistent_hash(
            list(sorted([session_consistent_hash(x, hash_object=None) for x in obj])),
            hash_object=hash_object
        )
    else:
        hash_object.update(hash(obj))
    return int(hash_object.hexdigest(), 16)
```

Answer (score -1):

I may have missed something here but at a high-level, I would approach this with serialization and hashing with hashlib.  That part is easy but your challenge is here:

> I can't guarantee that equal parameter objects will have identical serialization strings, only that, once deserialized, the objects will again be equal

So, as you are clearly aware, in order to have consistent hashing, you need to have a consistent serialization.  In the past when I've had similar issues, I've used recursive sorting routines on standard output formats e.g. XML.  Implementing something like that for JSON shouldn't be too hard but if you are doing this for general structures, then you have a different issue: not everything is JSON serializable by default.  I don't really know much about the pickle format.  On a quick glance at the  documentation, format 0 is said to be "human readable".  This might be a good place to start in working something out.  Clearly there are parsers for all the formats built into the standard lib so that might be an avenue for implementation.  It should also go without saying that you should look around for anything that might already provide part of such a solution.

Comment: JimmyJames, hashing will nowadays _intentionally_ return different results on different program runs for identical data.

Comment: @gnasher729 It's not clear what the context of your assertion is but that's not true in general. For example `md5_hash = md5(data).digest()` in python will return the same result for the same input regardless of when or where it is run.  In fact, any compliant md5 hash implemented in any language will return the same result.

Comment: As an example, the built-in hash function in Swift changed every time you run the software. AND that was exactly complained about.

Comment: @gnasher729 I was addressing this in the TLDR Question 1 section: "I can't guarantee that equal parameter objects will have identical serialization strings, only that, once deserialized, the objects will again be equal" which was given as a reason hashlib wouldn't work.